# Пляски с makemigrations продолжаются. Ошибка urls.py Как быть?

Tags: python-3.x, django

При проведение `makemigrations` вываливается вот такая прелесть

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\django\test_django\courses_django\lesson_sixth\urls.py", line 10, in <module>
    path('', List.as_view(), name ='list-view'),
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

вот **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import List


urlpatterns = [
    path('', List.as_view(), name ='list-view'),
]
```

Где здесь можно вкосячить  - не пойму... Но ошибка есть

Comment: Попытка обращения к несуществующей переменной, очевидно же.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import include, path
```

вот в чем была проблема